# Android how to restart an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

Red carefully before marking as duplicate:

How do I **restart** and activity in android terms within the activity. (just like when someone presses home button and goes back to the app). I do not want to redraw my activity so `onCreate` must not be called. Basically how to do `pause -> stop -> start -> resume`? (without `destroy or create`)

The main reason I would like to do this is that when I modify window flags they don't take effect imidiately but after pressing home and going back to the app they take effect. Any other suggestion on making sure they effect will be more than welcome. (`FLAG_SECURE` is the flag that is not taking effect immidiately)

I couldn't find anything regarding this all other similar questions involved redrawing the full activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not so clear when you start your activity again...

[image]

(from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

as you can see once your activity is stopped (after onStop() ) it can either be destroyed or restarted - but that depends on other activites which are out of our scope - so we don't know the context in wich you start/stop your activity...

-> there is no defined answer on your

keep the programming hints in mind:

Depending on the complexity of your activity, you probably don't need to implement all the lifecycle methods. However, it's important that you understand each one and implement those that ensure your app behaves the way users expect. Implementing your activity lifecycle methods properly ensures your app behaves well in several ways, including that it:

- Does not crash if the user receives a phone call or switches to another app while using your app.
- Does not consume valuable system resources when the user is not actively using it.
  Does not lose the user's progress if they leave your app and return to it at a later time.
- Does not crash or lose the user's progress when the screen rotates between landscape and portrait orientation.

(from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

### Killable

to make it even more clear for you: look at the table from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html where you see the stats and the flag killable...

...and that note:

Note the "Killable" column in the above table -- for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that method returns the process hosting the activity may killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. In addition, the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created. See the Process Lifecycle section for more information on how the lifecycle of a process is tied to the activities it is hosting. Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

Comment: So it is possible to use a dummy activity to call `pause -> stop` then use the dummy to navigate back to the original activity and do `start -> resume` ?

Comment: it is possible, but it is no guarantee to prevent you 'big major' activiy from being destroyed - if you have a very small mobil device (one with very little memory) your big major activity might get destroyed as well...

Comment: in the picture it is described as "user navigates to the activity" and there are TWO ways to navigate back to your activity...

Comment: if you navigate back to your activity and your current process needed too much ressources your original activity could have been destroyed and onCreate() will be called again!

Comment: one real good approach would be that you store and restore your data within the methods onStart()[restore]/onStop()[store]

Comment: I wanted to avoid the recreation to optamize it. There are only two booleans variable at the moment that I would like to pass but prefered it if It could be done without the ful recreation of the activity!

Comment: it might sound very stupid, but once your activity is stopped it is KILLABLE! look again at the table from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. if you want to prevent an activity to be NOT KILLABLE then activitiy is not an option for you... sorry...

Comment: I understand that and I remember it sounded very silly the first time I read the activity cycle for my hello android app :D But the worse case is that if it is killed, then recreate. If not then navigate back!

Comment: some of my activities stay alive if i show another activity - sometimes they get killed - i for myself have no influence on that behaviour and i learned that i ALWAYS store my activity data - even onPause() and onResume() (at least i can re-use my method storeData() and restoreData() in all all life-cycle-methods)

Comment: I'll accept your answer since at least you suggestion an implementable scenario which matchen my requirements. Saving data is a must I wanted to unnessecary computations in oncreate.

Comment: i don't know how else i could help - i had a lot of trouble geting over that life cycle and now i fnally learned that this is like some kind of LAW ... i have to cope with that as well as you have to :-/

Answer (score -1):

For restarting an activity you can do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned that he does not want to re create the Activity.

Comment: @VINIL SATRASALA wouldn't your suggestion call `onDestroy` and then `onCreate` ? I'm pretty sure it does!

Comment: I don't think `Start()` works since activity needs to be stopped first. Basically need to call this chain: `pause -> stop -> start -> resume`

Comment: have you tried it? I doubt that this will work! the `startActivity(...)` will not be marked as unreachable code but as my understanding of Android this is unreachable :-)

Comment: Again - the OP mentioned that he/she doesn't want to destroy or create the Activity.